# Overriding Constructors in F#

Tags: f#, constructor, overriding

How would I write the following C# code in F#?

```
namespace Shared {
    public class SharedRegistry : PageRegistry {
        public SharedRegistry(bool useCache = true)
            : base(useCache) {
            // Repositories
            ForRequestedType<IAddressRepository>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SqlAddressRepository>();
            ForRequestedType<ISharedEnquiryRepository>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SharedEnquiryRepository>();

            // Services
            ForRequestedType<IAddressService>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<AddressService>();
            ForRequestedType<ISharedEnquiryService>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SharedEnquiryService>();
        }
    }
}
```

As is as far as I have managed, but I can't work out to inherit from `PageRegistry` at the same time as declaring my own default constructor.

```
type SharedRegistry(useCache: bool) =
    inherit PageRegistry(useCache)
    new() = new SharedRegistry(true)
```

Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question; what you've written above looks like it ought to work fine.  If you're asking where to put the rest of the constructor logic, try this:

```
type SharedRegistry(useCache) as this =
  inherit PageRegistry(useCache)
  do
    this.ForRequestedType<IAddressRepository>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SqlAddressRepository>()
    // etc.
  new() = SharedRegistry(true)
```

If you want to define each constructor individually, you can do that too:

```
type SharedRegistry =
  inherit PageRegistry
  new(useCache) as this = 
    { inherit PageRegistry(useCache) } then
    this.ForRequestedType<IAddressRepository>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SqlAddressRepository>()
    // etc.
  new() = SharedRegistry(true)
```

Or, you could use an optional argument to your main constructor:

```
type SharedRegistry(?useCache) as this =
  inherit PageRegistry(defaultArg useCache true)
  do
    this.ForRequestedType<IAddressRepository>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SqlAddressRepository>()
    // etc.
```

Comment: The only amendment I have had to make is to wrap the StructureMap methods in Ignore() methods as they they return types.

Comment: @kim3er - Yes, if you call a function which returns a value, then you'll need to ignore it.  It would probably be more idiomatic to use `|> ignore` after the call than to put the whole thing in `ignore(...)`, but the methods are named so verbosely that neither option looks particularly good.

Answer (score 5):

Your C# class uses parameters with default value which is slightly different than overloaded constructors. In any case, F# supports both overloaded constructors and default parameters.

Using **default values** of a parameters, the code would look like this:

```
type SharedRegistry(?useCache: bool) = 
    do 
      // constructor logic
    inherit PageRegistry(defaultArg useCache true)
```

Now you can create an instance as follows:

```
let r1 = new SharedRegistry() // using the default value
let r2 = new SharedRegistry(false) // specified explicitly
let r3 = new SharedRegistry(useCache=false) // using named parameter
```

I belive that using named parameters is slightly more elegant in F#. The way it works is that the parameter `useCache` becomes an `option<bool>` under the cover (This may be a problem if you wanted to use the class from C#)

Regarding **overloaded constructors** - Your F# code should be correct (see the answer from *kvb*). In general, it is probably better to have at least one implicit constructor (as that allows you to access constructor parameters inside the body of the class automatically, declare fields using `let` and implement constructor logic using `do`). The implicit constructor should be the one that takes all the parameters. In some cases, you may want to make it private, which can be done like this:

```
type SharedRegistry private (useCache: bool) = 
    inherit PageRegistry(useCache) 
    do 
      // constructor logic
    new () = SharedRegistry(true)
```

Comment: One minor nitpick... the additional `new` in the constructor body is harmless; as in most cases in F# it's not required but can be used explicitly if desired.