# UICollectionViewCell Definition F#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, f#, uicollectionview

How would I translate the following C# code into F#:

```
public class AnimalCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
[Export ("initWithFrame:")]
  public AnimalCell (RectangleF frame) : base (frame) {}
}
```

I tried following the example in the below link, however, I do not know how to proceed next: 
[Overriding Constructors in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566821/overriding-constructors-in-f)

What I have come up with up till now is this:

```
[<Register ("AnimalCell")>]
type AnimalCell (handle: IntPtr) as this = 
    inherit UICollectionViewCell (handle)
```

where would I add the `Export` as well as the parameters? I know I should use `new()` but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will get you started:

#### `F#` UICollectionViewCell subclass

```
[<Register ("AnimalCell")>]
type AnimalCell =   
    inherit UICollectionViewCell

    [<DefaultValue>] static val mutable private id : NSString
    static member init = 
        printfn "Initializing AnimalCell."
        AnimalCell.id <- new NSString("animalCell")

    [<Export("init")>]
    new() = { inherit UICollectionViewCell() } then AnimalCell.init
    [<Export("initWithFrame:")>]
    new(frame: CGRect) = { inherit UICollectionViewCell(frame) } then AnimalCell.init
    [<Export("initWithCoder:")>]
    new(coder: NSCoder) = { inherit UICollectionViewCell(coder) } then AnimalCell.init

    new(handle: IntPtr) = { inherit UICollectionViewCell(handle) } then AnimalCell.init

    override this.ReuseIdentifier = AnimalCell.id
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error FS0762: Constructors for the type 'AnimalCell' must directly or indirectly call its implicit object constructor. Use a call to the implicit object constructor instead of a record expression. (FS0762)` on all three of the lines starting with `new`

Comment: I think its because of the `handle` I use in my original code which you have removed in the answer. I need to have this handle as it is used later on in the class.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @Alk The `Handle` based constructor is just another inherited .actor that you can provide to the type, I updated my answer

Comment: does this allow me to keep the `as this` part? I need this because i set up constraints in code, for example :         `this.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(....)` so I need to have access to `this`

Comment: If this UICollectionViewCell is never created via the ObjC runtime you do not need all the other .actors, normally you would never use the Handle-based constructor directly, but if you do for your use-case make it your main constructor and remove all the exportable .actors

Comment: Thanks! One more question, in my `viewdidload` of the `UICollectionViewController` I am doing the following: `        `x.CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(AnimalCell), new NSString("animalCell"))`, however this doesn't seem to work throwing two errors: `: Error FS0685: The generic function 'typeof' must be given explicit type argument(s) (FS0685)` and `Error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied. (FS0003)`

Comment: @Alk `typeof<AnimalCell>`